# How to add icon set to resources and then allow user to choose from icons in "choose icon" dialog? (for a task in a list)

Tags: android, icons

In my Android app I would like to allow a user to **pick an icon from an icon set** (either from my own icon set available in resources, or from external icon apps). He would click on choose icon (or on existing icon) and a **dialog with a grid of icons** would appear. Clicking on icon would select it.

How do I do that? And if I'll be using an Array of string of resources, how do I add conveniently 100+ icons to resources and then to the array?

How can I make my app use installed icon packs to pick such icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. try to pop up a custom dialog on chooseIcon/ existing Icon click.
2. Add all your icons to your drawables folder. And create a ArrayList in your app with those icons.
3. Create a custom adapter and pass this ArrayList to adapter. There is no convenient way..